# Reading input in bash in an infinite loop and reacting to it

Tags: bash, loops, input

So I want to wait 1 second for some input (options that i will implement later).
Or i want the program to print something(will implement later too). I have run into a problem tho, when trying to read that 1 char for the function, here is my code:

```
while true
   do read $var -t 1
      case $var in
          ("h")
              help
              ;;
      esac
done
```

If I try to echo after the case, the program does wait for 1 second, the problem is it doesnt recognise my h input, how would i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your sample slightly so that it works. There was an error in the read statement. use `read var`instead of `read $var`. This corrected sample will now recognise also the `h` input.

Related to your question Why it doesn't wait the second (*which was btw. hard to determine so i increased the timeout a bit ;-)* )? This is because when you enter something, the read timeout is interrupted. It is as the parameter name say's a timeout for the user input. So if the user input's something the timeout is interrupted.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true 
do
      echo 'wait for input ...'

      read -t 10 var

      echo 'got input ...'

      case $var in
        h)
          echo 'help'
        ;;
      esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks, its an assignment for school, it need to list info of the current processes and refresh it every second, also change what it outputs depending on you pressing certain keys